# How to fix PDF in a bootstrap modal appearing out of the modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a PDF to show in a bootstrap modal. Although it is appearing and all the modal functionality is working the PDF displays to the right of the modal

I have tried increasing the modal width.

***HTML:***

```
<div class='col-3'>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Application_ccps.pdf</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <object width=500 height=575 data="Application_ccps.pdf"></object>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default" id="thepanel">
                <div class="panel-heading" id="panelheading">Documents submitted: 5</div>
                <div class="panel-body" id="panelbody">
                  <img src="pdficon.png"> &nbsp; <button class="pdfbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Application_ccps.pdf</button><br>
                  <img src="pdficon.png"> &nbsp; <button class="pdfbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Application_ccps.pdf</button><br>
                  <img src="pdficon.png"> &nbsp; <button class="pdfbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Application_ccps.pdf</button><br>
                  <img src="pdficon.png"> &nbsp; <button class="pdfbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Application_ccps.pdf</button><br>
                  <img src="pdficon.png"> &nbsp; <button class="pdfbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Application_ccps.pdf</button><br>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

***CSS:***

```
#thepanel {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 500px;
      line-height: 30px;
      font-family: Segoe UI;
    }

.pdfbutton {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
}

.modal-body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

The expected result is for when the PDF names are clicked a PDF pops up contained within the modal however this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: an image would be useful for this case

Answer (score 0):

you could create an individual modal for each file, and set different ids for each so you can call them on your buttons

```
<img src="pdficon.png"> &nbsp; <button class="pdfbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal01">Application_ccps.pdf</button><br>

<div class='col-3'>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal01" role="dialog">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use iframe instead of the object tag.

```
<iframe width=500 height=575 src="path_to_your_pdf.pdf"></iframe>
```